# How to mass update Leads into Queue using Dataloader.io?

Tags: queue, dataloader.io

Using [Dataloader.io](https://dataloader.io/) how can I mass update a list of leads to belong to a Queue? I tried setting the OwnerID to be the Queue SF ID but it didn't work.

Searching the SF forums it appears you need to set Record Owner. [This answer talks about using dataloader.io](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000D44xAAC) with OwnerID.

It seems like I am missing something obvious. :)

Comment: You should just have to set the OwnerId field to the Id of the Queue. Where are you getting the Queue Id from? Are you getting an error back?

Comment: It finally worked. Is there an easier way to get a Queue ID than going to Setup>Queue>click the Queue and copy out of the URL?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it resolved your problem @JoshuaDance :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to assign a record to a queue you would set the `OwnerId` field to the Id of the Queue. There are two ways you can go about getting the Queue Id:

1. Go to `Setup -> Manage Users -> Queues` and select the queue you want to get the ID of. You can then get the Id from the URL:

   [image]
2. Querying it with SOQL, which can be done in the developer console:

   `SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Type='Queue' AND Name='MY_QUEUE_NAME'`